# Understanding RFC6598 (CGN)

Tags: rfc

I'm having a discussion with an ISP whether or not we should receive traffic from `100.64.0.0/10` on our firewall.

The way I see it we should only receive traffic from their NAT device and not directly from the shared address space.

The RFC states:

> Shared Address Space is IPv4 address space designated for Service
>      Provider use with the purpose of facilitating CGN deployment.  Also,
>      Shared Address Space can be used as additional non-globally routable
>      space on routing equipment that is able to do address translation
>      across router interfaces when the addresses are identical on two
>      different interfaces.
>
> Devices MUST be capable of performing address translation when
>      identical Shared Address Space ranges are used on two different
>      interfaces.
>
> Packets with Shared Address Space source or destination addresses
>      MUST NOT be forwarded across Service Provider boundaries.  Service
>      Providers MUST filter such packets on ingress links.  One exception
>      to this paragraph's proscription is in the case of business
>      relationships, such as hosted CGN services.

I read the above as that the shared address space should only be used between the customers CPE and the ISPs NAT device and therefore should never reach my firewall.

Here is an image of the topology (simplified)
[image]

Am I misunderstanding the RFC or is the ISP?

Comment: What's the topology? Where do you receive this traffic? Much depends on what you agreed on.

Comment: @TeunVink - Added an image of the topology and where I receive the traffic. We receive the traffic on our firewall through the ISPs CPE on our end. I would expect the traffic to come through the ISPs NAT gateway before reaching us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really follow your argument. From your network perspective, the Shared Address is your public address. Your outside address (usually on your firewall) will be in the Shared Address space, then you can use NAT to translate your inside addresses to the Shared Address (your outside address).

If the ISP has two customers within its Shared Address space, then those two customers may directly communicate using their outside (Shared Address) addresses.

Basically, an ISP is using the Share Address space as its inside network, and you are connecting to its inside network as your outside network.

---

As far as I know, ISPs are only using Shared Address space for residential customers, saving the pools of public addresses for their business customers.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood the question - I am not having a shared address, I have a regular, globally routable address. The customer connecting to me is having a shared address and therefore my firewall is communicating directly with a peer in the shared address space instead of through the NAT gateway

Comment: If you and the other router are on the same ISP, then you could receive traffic from the Shared Address space, which is the outside address of the other router. There is nothing wrong with that. The ISP just cannot send the Shared Addresses outside its AS, but it is free to use them inside its AS.

Comment: Okay so technically they are not breaching the RFC when routing the shared address space but could it be stated as sub-optimal network design? We are a business customer with a /29 subnet and the "other customer" is a residential user. This whole case comes from the fact that our firewall (opnsense) by default blocks bogon & RFC1918 on the WAN link which includes the shared address space so we need to poke holes in our firewall to allow other customers of this particular ISP to reach our services.

Comment: You could have another problem if you had a different ISP because many don't use Shared Address space, opting to use Private Address (RFC 1918) space. Since the ISPs will not allow either Shared Address or Private Address space between them, you really shouldn't need to worry about blocking that inbound on your network, only outbound from your network to the ISP. Also, it would be a poor design to force all internal traffic using that address space through a NAT device to only turn it back around to inside the network. The ISP seems to be using the most direct path (good network design).

Comment: Allright, i'll give up my quest on blaming the ISP for having to force me to open up my firewall.